# For-loop condition

Tags: c++, for-loop

The condition `m[i][j] != 0` in second loop produces error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` in clion on some reason. I simplified an example. I want to subscribe vector until I meet zero or until the end of it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int matrixElementsSum(std::vector<std::vector<int>> m) {
    for (int j = 0; j != m[0].size(); ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; (m[i][j] != 0) && (i != m.size()); ++i) {
            std::cout << m[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix = { {1, 1, 1, 0} };
    int s = matrixElementsSum(matrix);
    std::cout << "s = " << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: And what would that error be?

Comment: Have you used a debugger to inspect the values of `i`, `j` and `m` at the time of the error? Also those loop conditions are needlessly complicated and prone to errors (`i < m.size()` is more reliable than `i != m.size()`, also you should be preferring range-based `for` loops unless you require the index for something else)

Comment: @UnholySheep yep! Error appears on the line of second loop so I don't see 
`i` in variables, only `j = 0` and  `m = {std::__...}`.

Comment: An aside: it's not the cause of your problem, but you should avoid comparing signed values (such as `i` and `j`) against unsigned values (such as `m.size()`).  If your compiler is not warning you about that, you need to ask it to be more picky for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; (m[i][j] != 0) && (i != m.size()); ++i)
```

`m[i][j] != 0` will be executed before check for size (`i != m.size()`), hence when `i == m.size()` you will be accessing out of bounds, and invoking undefined behavior.

To fix such an issue, you may use C++ short-circuit evaluation, and rewrite the condition like this:

```
for (int i = 0; (i != m.size()) && (m[i][j] != 0); ++i)
```

If the size is reached - entire condition would be `false` anyway, hence the `m[i][j] != 0` will not be executed.

Comment: Ah, I see! Recently I already found such bugs but this time I missed it. Thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

I think, that the condition in first loop should look like this:

```
j != m.size()
```

Not `j != m[0].size()`

Comment: And also the second one: `(i != m[j].size())`. Then you have to use values from array as `m[j][i]` - don't do `m[i][j]`.

Comment: I want to have subscription on transposed matrix! That is why inversed iteration

Answer (score 1):

Its bad access because you are trying to access garbage via `(m[i][j] != 0) && (i != m.size())` in the `matrixElementSums` function

To solve this problem add the overflow condition first rather than testing the value condition via `(i != m.size()) && (m[i][j] != 0)`

Answer (score 0):

`m[0].size()` has undefined behaviour if `m` is empty. `m` might not be empty in your function call, but at the time `matrixElementsSum` is analysed, the static analyser cannot know all the ways the function will be called.

Furthermore, it assumes that the vector of vectors is rectangular - i.e. all rows are the same width, since you only compare with the size of first row, and not the rest. This might be the case for matrices, but the static analyser doesn't know what a matrix is.

Finally, `m[i][j] != 0` is out of bounds when `i > m.size()`. You need to check that first. This is the worst problem, since the others can be dealt with documentation of pre-conditions of the function, while this bug occurs with any input.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid all the silly errors in your code by using range-based `for` loops like this:

```
int matrixElementsSum(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& m) {
    for (auto const& row: m) {
        for (auto const& value: row) {
            std::cout << value << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Much less confusing, and much easier to get right!